# StopLoss is not getting hit

Tags: pine-script

I need some help on this code, the intent is to execute stoploss with a high/low of the prior to entry candle
but it doesn't hit that stoploss, what is wrong?

```
//@version=4 
strategy("Support and Resistance Breakout Strategy", overlay=true)

// Indicator Inputs 
toggleBreaks  = input(true, title = "Show Breaks" ) 
leftBars  = input(15, title = "Left Bars ") 
rightBars  = input(15, title = "Right Bars") 
volumeThresh  = input(20, title = "Volume Threshold")

// Support and Resistance Levels 
highUsePivot = fixnan(pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1]) 
lowUsePivot = fixnan(pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])

// Volume % 
short = ema(volume, 5) 
long = ema(volume, 10) 
osc = 100 * (short - long) / long

// 20 EMA 
ema20 = ema(close, 20)

// Breakout Signals 
breakoutUp = crossover(close, highUsePivot) 
breakoutDown = crossunder(close, lowUsePivot)

// Stop Loss and Take Profit 
 
sell_sl = valuewhen(breakoutUp, high[1], 0) 
buy_sl = valuewhen(breakoutDown, low[1], 0) 
tp_pips = input(title="Take Profit (pips)", defval=10)

// Buy Signal if breakoutUp 
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long) 
strategy.exit("Buy Close", "Buy", limit=tp_pips,stop=buy_sl)

// Sell Signal if breakoutDown 
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short) 
strategy.exit("Sell Close", "Sell", limit=tp_pips, stop=sell_sl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plot `tp_pips` and `buy_sl` and you will see.

Your stop loss is on the other side of the price most of the times so it acts as a take profit.

Also, the `limit` parameter of `strategy.exit()` expects a price input and not pips. You can try using the `profit` argument which expects the tarket specified in ticks.

Comment: @vitrusvius , All I am trying to achieve is to Take Profit at 10 points and stop L on previous to entry candles low/high, how can I acheive it? Appreciate the help